# Creating sockets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I'm trying to create a socket in qt. The code I use is the following. In qt, the standard `connect()` is in conflict with `connect()` used for socket connection. How can I fix this?

```
int sock_Desc   = 0;
if (proxy_port == 0) {
    proxy_port = 3773;
}
sock_Desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(127.0.0.1);
server.sin_family       = AF_INET;
server.sin_port         = htons(proxy_port);
connect(sock_Desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)); 
int rc = 0;
if ((option & 1) == 0) {
    if(send(sock_Desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) {
        close(sock_Desc); 
    }
    if ((option & 2) == 2) {
        rc = recv(sock_Desc, rcv_Msg, 512, 0);
        if (rc == 0) {
            close(sock_Desc); 
        }
        if (rc < 0) {
            close(sock_Desc); 
        }
    }
} else {
    if(option & 2 == 2) {
        rc = system(message);
    }
}

close(sock_Desc);
```

Comment: If this is Qt, why don't I see any Qt code? Why don't you simply use the Qt sockets, i.e. QTcpSocket?

Comment: i wanttouse this code with qt code.

Answer (score 4):

The function `connect` from the socket header (`sys/socket.h` on linux) is in the global namespace since it's a C header file. You can explicitly refer to the global namespace by writing

```
::connect(sock_Desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
```